# SQL: Find the max record per group

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

I have one table, which has three fields and data.

```
Name  , Top , Total
cat   ,   1 ,    10
dog   ,   2 ,     7
cat   ,   3 ,    20
horse ,   4 ,     4
cat   ,   5 ,    10
dog   ,   6 ,     9
```

I want to select the record which has highest value of `Total` for each `Name`, so my result should be like this:

```
Name  , Top , Total
cat   ,   3 ,    20
horse ,   4 ,     4
Dog   ,   6 ,     9
```

I tried group by name order by total, but it give top most record of group by result. Can anyone guide me, please?

Comment: I wonder how many duplicates there are for this query - certainly many more than just one.  See the 60+ questions tagged 'greatest-n-per-group' (for the cases n=1).

Comment: @Jonathan: This is the "forever question" in the field of beginner SQL questions. There's a fresh one every day on SO.

Answer (score 38):

```
select
  Name, Top, Total
from
  sometable
where
  Total = (select max(Total) from sometable i where i.Name = sometable.Name)
```

or

```
select
  Name, Top, Total
from
  sometable
  inner join (
    select max(Total) Total, Name
    from sometable
    group by Name
  ) as max on max.Name = sometable.Name and max.Total = sometable.Total
```

Comment: hi sir,
thanks for your quick reply.

i also created one query just now, and its giving me perfect result.
here is my query


 select Name, Top, total from animals where total in(SELECT max(total) FROM `animals` group by name) group by name


my question is, which is more efficient, yours or mine when table contain 2 millions of data?

thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Which is more efficient? Define proper indexes on your table and try it out. Apart from that, your `WHERE total in (...)` is wrong. You would quickly see this once you try with *actual* millions of records and not just a hand full.

Comment: The second query is likely to more efficient than the first because the first uses a correlated sub-query which might be executed many times instead of just once in the second version.

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  s.*
FROM    sometable s INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Name,
                    MAX(Total) MTotal
            FROM    sometable
            GROUP BY Name
        ) sMax  ON  s.Name = sMax.Name 
                AND s.Total = sMax.MTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using an Exists clause, wich returns the only row that exists in both tables

```
SELECT * from sometable T
where exists
(select 1
from (SELECT nombre, max(total) as total FROM  sometable TT
    GROUP by nombre) TT
where T.name=TT.name
and T.total=TT.total
)
```

Comment: This will work, with the caveat about it being expensive on big tables with a naïve optimizer that does not manage to execute the correlated sub-query just once.

Comment: @Jonathan +1 solely for using the diacritical i in "naïve". :-)