# MySQL Query Output

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this query however it's only outputting results of categories that have items in them, rather than all the categories. This is my query:

```
SELECT categories.`id` as `cat_id`, categories.`title` as `cat_title`, COUNT(tutorials.`id`) as `total`
FROM `tutorial_categories` as `categories`, `tutorials`
WHERE tutorials.`category` = categories.id
GROUP BY `cat_id`
```

Can anyone lead me in the right direction here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
categories.id , 
categories.title,
COUNT(*) as total
FROM tutorial_categories as categories
LEFT JOIN tutorials
on tutorials.category = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.id
```

Comment: You wouldn't be able to direct me as to how I could get the latest ID from the `tutorials` table as well for each category?

Comment: There are a lot of questions about this problem. This is just an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657482/sql-find-the-max-record-per-group   Open a new thread if it doesn't solve. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN`. Your implicit join syntax produces an inner join insetad:

```
SELECT 
  categories.`id` as `cat_id`, 
  categories.`title` as `cat_title`, 
  COUNT(tutorials.`id`) as `total`
FROM
  `tutorial_categories` `categories` LEFT JOIN `tutorials`  ON categories.id = tutorials.category
GROUP BY `cat_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an outer join as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) : "An outer join does not require each record in the two joined tables to have a matching record"

Answer (score 0):

You need to restyle the query using an outer join, instead of using the WHERE

Something like this

```
SELECT categories.`id` as `cat_id`, categories.`title` as `cat_title`, COUNT(tutorials.`id`) as `total`
FROM `tutorial_categories` as `categories`, `tutorials`
LEFT OUTER JOIN tutorials.`category` = categories.id
GROUP BY `cat_id`
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a `WHERE tutorials.`category`= categories.id` set so it would only return the rows that meet that criteria.  Remove that and it should return "all the categories".

```
SELECT categories.`id` as `cat_id`, categories.`title` as `cat_title`, COUNT(tutorials.`id`) as `total`
FROM `tutorial_categories` as `categories`, `tutorials`
GROUP BY `cat_id`
```

Comment: Removing the where will result in a cartesian product number of results, it needs a defined join, rather than a where

Comment: @DanKelly yeah my bad.  I missed the , in the From clause.