# Grails named query to select row based on the max value in multiple rows

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have a groovy multi select tag () in which I want to display only the row which has MAX revision from a set of rows. Here is a post which does it in SQL: [to select single row based on the max value in multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723404/how-to-select-single-row-based-on-the-max-value-in-multiple-rows/8723520#8723520)?

How can I write in groovy? Should I create a named query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve this. Those include namedQueries, criteria, detached criteria or even HQL. Here is the namedQuery which would get what is needed:

```
static namedQueries = {
    maxRevision {
        eq 'revision', {
            projections {
                max 'revision'
            }
        }
        //projections if needed
        projections {
            property 'name'
        }
    }
}

//controller
AppInfo.maxRevision().list()
```

With a detached criteria, it would be similar as:

```
AppInfo.withCriteria {
    eq 'revision', {
        projections {
            max 'revision'
        }
    }

    projections {
        property 'name'
    }
}
```

with HQL:

```
select ai from AppInfo as ai 
where ai.revision = (
    select max(revision) from AppInfo
)
```

taking into consideration this below domain class:

```
class AppInfo {
    String name
    Integer revision 
}
```

**UPDATE**
Above would give the max of all the revisions. If you are looking for max of each group then you will have to use the below HQL:

```
AppInfo.executeQuery("""
                      select ai from AppInfo as ai 
                      where ai.revision in (
                          select max(a.revision) from AppInfo as a 
                          where a.name = ai.name
                      )
                    """)
```

This can also be written as a Criteria.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro.. I tried the named query. However, it returns only one row. I want to select all name in AppInfo with highest revision number...

Comment: Thank you.. I got a similar SQL code but its bad in performance..There is a better SQL solution by @Jonathan Leffler link below...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723404/how-to-select-single-row-based-on-the-max-value-in-multiple-rows/8723520#8723520

Comment: I tried to write the last query mentioned and came to this (does`nt work, it gives out all the records). Any pointers to solve this @dmahapatro?
        def join =  AppInfo.list {
            groupProperty("name")
            max('revision')
            }