# Find the max record per group, with additional fields

Tags: sql, max, inner-join

I have one table named `tgps`, which has six fields and data

```
Model   ftype   serial  Date        latitude        longitude
Car     B       2142    15/09/2014  S11.59.41.194   W077.07.33.184
Car     A       2123    15/09/2014  S12.15.12.245   W076.55.08.194
Truck   A       2123    16/09/2014  S13.42.48.122   W071.53.22.081
PickUp  C       2111    14/09/2014  S14.36.05.071   W075.11.47.133
PickUp  A       2111    15/09/2014  S14.39.51.245   W075.10.00.000
PickUp  A       2111    14/09/2014  S14.41.14.040   W075.07.12.245
Truck   B       2123    13/09/2014  S14.42.51.092   W075.05.35.133
Car     B       2142    14/09/2014  S14.46.14.040   W070.20.03.030
Truck   A       2123    13/09/2014  S15.54.53.163   W071.11.21.153
Truck   B       2123    16/09/2014  S15.58.40.051   W071.12.48.122
Car     A       2123    16/09/2014  S16.18.06.061   W069.16.24.122
Car     C       2142    13/09/2014  S16.29.27.092   W071.51.48.122
```

I want to select the record which has highest value of `Date` for each `Model`, `ftype` and `serial`, and also need to display the `latitude` and `longitude`, so my result should be like this:

```
Model   ftype   serial  Date        latitude        longitude
Car     A       2123    16/09/2014  S16.18.06.061   W069.16.24.122
Car     B       2142    15/09/2014  S11.59.41.194   W077.07.33.184
PickUp  A       2111    15/09/2014  S14.39.51.245   W075.10.00.000
PickUp  C       2111    14/09/2014  S14.36.05.071   W075.11.47.133
Truck   A       2123    16/09/2014  S13.42.48.122   W071.53.22.081
Truck   B       2123    16/09/2014  S15.58.40.051   W071.12.48.122
```

This needs an inner join with concatenate fields (`Model`, `ftype` and `serial`), I tried something as:

```
SELECT model + ftype + serial, date, latitude, longitude
FROM (
    SELECT model + ftype + serial, max(date) 
    FROM tgps group by model, ftype, serial) 
as xw inner join tgps on tgps.model + tgps.ftype + tgps.serial = xw.model + xw.ftype + xw.serial
and tgps.date = xw.max(date)
```

but it's not working.

Comment: try use to concat || instead +

Comment: the last part of your SQL doesn't make much sense to me. It should probably be `tgps.date = Max(xw.date)`

I am not looking much more into this though so who knows if that will work. If you format the SQL to be more readable, it might get more answers.

Comment: also, "not working" is probably the worst possible description of a problem someone can give on stackoverflow. Provide logs and error messages in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Find the max record per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657482/sql-find-the-max-record-per-group)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple subquery linked to the main SELECT to get the max date from each entity:

```
select 
    Model, ftype, serial, Date, latitude, longitude
from
    tgps T
where
    Date = 
        (
            select
                max(Date)
            from
                tgps
            where
                Model = T.Model
                and ftype = T.ftype
                and serial = T.serial
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to get your max date for each model, ftype, and serial.  Then you can join that to your table to get the lat and long for those values.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81a03/6)

```
with CTE as
(select
 model,
 ftype,
 serial,
 max(date) as maxdate
from
tgps
group by
 model,
 ftype,
 serial
)

select
t1.*

from
tgps t1
inner join cte t2
  on t1.model = t2.model
  and t1.ftype = t2.ftype
  and t1.serial = t2.serial
  and t1.date = t2.maxdate

order by t1.model,
t1.ftype
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select all rows where another row with a greater date and the same model, ftype and serial does `not exist`

```
select * from tgps t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from tgps t2
    where t2.model = t1.model
    and t2.ftype = t1.ftype
    and t2.serial = t1.serial
    and t2.date > t1.date
)
```

or if you have access to analytic functions this will be faster

```
select * from (
  select *, 
  row_number() over (partition by model, ftype, serial order by date desc) rn
from tgps) t1 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody, this is how I solved my problem:

```
SELECT tgps.model + tgps.ftype + tgps.serial,tgps.lat, tgps.lng, tgps.Date FROM tgps INNER JOIN (
    SELECT model, ftype, serial, max(Date) junto
    FROM tgps group by model, ftype, serial) 
as xw on tgps.Date = xw.junto and tgps.serial = xw.serial and tgps.ftype = xw.ftype and tgps.model = xw.model
```