# Update flag for columns with max date PER group

Tags: mysql

Imagine the following table:

```
Id      type       created                      flag
-----------------------------------------------------
1          1        2015-12-11 12:00:00          0
2          1        2015-12-11 12:10:00          0
3          2        2015-12-11 12:00:00          0
4          2        2015-12-11 12:10:00          0
5          3        2015-12-11 12:00:00          0
6          3        2015-12-11 12:10:00          0
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a query that will set the flag to 1 (TRUE) for each row with the most recent created date for each type grouping. Ex, the result should be:

```
Id      type       created                      flag
-----------------------------------------------------
1          1        2015-12-11 12:00:00          0
2          1        2015-12-11 12:10:00          1
3          2        2015-12-11 12:00:00          0
4          2        2015-12-11 12:10:00          1
5          3        2015-12-11 12:00:00          0
6          3        2015-12-11 12:10:00          1
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I know that

```
UPDATE table
SET flag = TRUE
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

will set the flag for the most recent date, but I'm stuck on how to apply this for each group.

I've also tried:

```
UPDATE table t
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT id, flag, MAX(created) as maxdate
    FROM table
    GROUP BY type) as m
SET flag = TRUE
WHERE m.id = t.id AND t.created = m.maxdate;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Find the max record per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657482/sql-find-the-max-record-per-group)

Comment: What was wrong with your edit attempt? Oh, you've slightly muddled up the subquery and I'd use an ON clause before the SET rather than a WHERE clause after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET flag = 1 
WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM(SELECT id, type FROM table 
ORDER BY created DESC) AS t GROUP BY type t.type);
```

Comment: @Strawberry Show me your wersio and I willing to give you a plus :)

Comment: this is close but not quite, it is still updating the wrong record... possibly because it orders by date first, the groupings dont necessarily have the max created date

Comment: It should be `ORDER BY created DESC` and you are missing the table name after `UPDATE` but this works. Thank you very much.