# Avoid duplicates during joins

Tags: php, mysql, join

Let's assume I've got this database:

```
table1:
- id
- name
```

and

```
table2:
-id
-name
-date
-table1id
```

If I do something like

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name,table2.date
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1id
```

I will have 2 rows.

I just would like to join the row from table2 with the most recent date. Is there a way to do it via MySQL, or must I do it with something like PHP after the query?

*In fine* I want one row, with table1.id, table1.name and the most recent date from the linked entries from table2.

Comment: Yes, use WHERE table2.date

Comment: WHERE table2.date = ?

Comment: I also want to know `where table2.date` what???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2657495 and deal with tie-breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and aggregation function [`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max):

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, MAX(table2.date) AS `date`
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1id
GROUP BY table1.id
```