# SQL - Create a distinct list based on datetime

Tags: sql

I'm trying to retrieve a list of results where there are multiple rows which have a duplicate field in different rows but only want to retrieve the row which has been created most recently

Data

```
loc     |   created            |   dest    |   w   |   l   |   h          
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2       |   2020/11/09 07:00:00 |   north   |   12  |   10  |   34
3       |   2020/11/09 07:10:00 |   south   |   34  |   67  |   23
3       |   2020/11/09 08:13:00 |   west    |   67  |   22  |   12
```

I have tried the the following which does give me the rows I require but is missing the extra columns which I require.

```
Select loc, MAX(created)
from Data
Group By loc
```

Results Required

```
loc     |   created            |   dest    |   w   |   l   |   h          
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2       |   2020/11/09 07:00:00 |   north   |   12  |   10  |   34
3       |   2020/11/09 08:13:00 |   west    |   67  |   22  |   12
```

Comment: select t1.* from (select loc, created, dest, w, l, h from Data) t1 join (select loc, max(created) as max_created from Data group by loc) t2 on t1.loc = t2.loc
and t1.created = t2.max_created;

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657482/sql-find-the-max-record-per-group

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by loc order by created desc) rn
    from Data
) t
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with max_vals as (
Select loc, MAX(created) as max_created
from Data
Group By loc
)
select d.*
from Data d join max_vals m
on d.loc = m.loc and d.created = m.max_created
```